# What is the process for solving second order linear differential with nonconstant coefficients?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was reading through some of the extra sections we had not covered in my differential equations class and they describe a method for solving non-constant equations. It never really showed how to solve. Just a bunch of ways to show it exists on a certain interval.

Could someone describe what this method is of solving them (obviously integration may fail) and also (if the person is aware) make it clear which things come from the knowledge that antiderivates vary by constants? I know that sounds weird but it useful for me to know precisely what things come from the set of antiderivatives varying by constants. It allows me to use a few special tricks I know for harder problems involving piecewise continuity.

The specific equation form the section seemed to be discussing how to solve was:

> $y'' + f_1(x)y' + f_2(x)y = g(x)$

It did mention transforming to the standard form but since I understand that there is no need to have it as anything else. It said there was a way to solve these for continuous f's and g and also how to prove the existence. However, it never actually said how to find the integral. If needed, I am willing to accept that g is zero. I am aware of the annihilator method so that probably comes immediately into play in dealing with g.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite honestly, I think that the answer is a lot longer than you were anticipating. There are *many* methods to solving such equations. You usually have to take it case by case.

First and foremost, we must separate the techniques into three categories.

**1)** Numerical methods such as Euler Method, midpoint method, and Runge-Kutta Fourth Order are great tools for approximating the value of such functions over a range. In essence, they perform the raw definite integration of the differential equation using a specified number of iterative steps.

**2)** If you already have $1$ solution, either determined from some alternative method, or perhaps found by sheer luck or circumstance of the problem, reduction of order can be used. This works analogously to undetermined coefficients, where you guess a solution comprised of your known solution and some other unknown function that you must solve for. Consequently, this method converts the 2nd order equation into a first order linear, so an integrating factor can be used.

If you know the general solution to the homogeneous equation, you can use variation of parameters to find a solution to the non-homogeneous equation.

**3)** As for actually *solving* the equation, power series method can be used in the case that the point you're expanding around isn't singular. This method entails assuming that $y$ can be written as an infinite sum of x-powers with coefficients that you solve for. This leads to a recursion, which in some case can be related back to the Taylor series of some known function to obtain a closed solution. If you are given initial conditions, it may be easiest to Laplace transform the equation, get it into a tangible form, and then inverse Laplace transform the result. Most methods become quite ugly to work with in non-linear cases, and may not even be solvable analytically, in which case we must return to numerical approximations